# Are the Light Side and the Dark Side "real"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Users of the Force often refer to the "Light Side" and the "Dark Side". Is there any indication that there is an actual separation in the Force between these two sides, or do the terms just refer to moral/ideological differences?

For example, force lightning is often thought of as a Dark Side power, given its destructive nature and that it is predominantly used by those on the Dark Side. But if, say, a Force user wanted to charge a depowered droid with a jolt of electricity (and assuming force lightning would do the trick) would they be forced to actually tap into the "Dark Side"?

Comment: Someone else can expand this into a full answer if they wish, but the Father, Son, and Daughter from the Clone Wars would seem to indicate that the Light/Dark dichotomy is part of the nature of the Force itself, not just a artificial construct of its users. https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)

Comment: No, they’re entirely fictional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the light/dark dichotomy is a aspect of the Force itself rather than an artificial construct imposed on it by its users.

In season three of the Clone Wars cartoon, there is a three episode arc ([Overlords](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Overlords), [Altar of Mortis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Altar_of_Mortis_(episode)), [Ghosts of Mortis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ghosts_of_Mortis)) where we are introduced to the [Father](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)), [Son](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Son) and [Daughter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Daughter).

It's a little unclear what exactly their relationship to the Force is. They seem to be members of a species of Force-users called [Force Wielders](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_wielder), so they are not manifestations of the Force itself. But the story presents each of them as the personification of an aspect of the Force with the Daughter, Son and Father personifying the light-side, dark-side and balance respectively.

Comment: I haven't seen the episode, but is it made clear that their personification is related to an innate aspect of the Force, rather than just an interpretation of it?

Comment: It's never explicitly said either way that I remember, but I interpreted it as them being personifications of innate aspects